# What's preventing my ping packets from getting routed?

Tags: ip, routing

## What I would like to do

I would like to set up my Debian Stretch GNU/Linux machine to route IP packets between its network interfaces.

## Context

These are the network interfaces of available on my Debian box and soon-to-be router:

| Index | interface name | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | enp2s0 | 192.168.23.91/24 |
| 2 | enx00e04c360e75 | 192.168.1.1/24 |
| 3 | enx000ec667a74a | 192.168.2.2/24 |

- `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` returns `1`, hence routing is enabled.
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` returns nothing but `0`s. Hence, reverse path filtering is disabled. (This was the source of concern for a few other questions I found.)

The routing table looks as follows:

```
$ sudo route -nn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.23.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enx00e04c360e75
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enx000ec667a74a
192.168.23.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

## The following works

From my device (`192.168.1.111`) connected on NIC 2, I can ping both my NIC 2 (`192.168.1.1`) as well as
NIC 3 (`192.168.2.2`).

`tcpdump` output on my Debian router looks as expected:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enx00e04c360e75 icmp -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enx00e04c360e75, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:10:51.919808 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 25404, seq 17, length 64
18:10:51.919863 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25404, seq 17, length 64
18:10:52.920019 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 25404, seq 18, length 64
18:10:52.920130 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25404, seq 18, length 64
18:10:53.920808 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 25404, seq 19, length 64
18:10:53.920895 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25404, seq 19, length 64
[...]
18:11:03.408546 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 25916, seq 0, length 64
18:11:03.408622 IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25916, seq 0, length 64
18:11:04.405006 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 25916, seq 1, length 64
18:11:04.405061 IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25916, seq 1, length 64
18:11:05.405147 IP 192.168.1.111 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 25916, seq 2, length 64
18:11:05.405201 IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.1.111: ICMP echo reply, id 25916, seq 2, length 64
```

## The following doesn't work

From my device connected via NIC 2, I cannot ping some host accessible through NIC 1.

`tcpdump` running on my Debian box shows incoming packets on NIC 2:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enx00e04c360e75 icmp -n
listening on enx00e04c360e75, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:11:31.837778 IP 192.168.1.111 > 193.99.144.80: ICMP echo request, id 36668, seq 4, length 64
18:11:32.838830 IP 192.168.1.111 > 193.99.144.80: ICMP echo request, id 36668, seq 5, length 64
18:11:33.838249 IP 192.168.1.111 > 193.99.144.80: ICMP echo request, id 36668, seq 6, length 64
[...]
```

but they never leave through NIC 1:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 icmp -n
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
[nothing]
```

When I issue the pings directly from my Debian router box, `tcpdump` looks like expected:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 icmp -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:35:16.577795 IP 192.168.23.91 > 193.99.144.80: ICMP echo request, id 13146, seq 1, length 64
18:35:16.600861 IP 193.99.144.80 > 192.168.23.91: ICMP echo reply, id 13146, seq 1, length 64
18:35:17.578164 IP 192.168.23.91 > 193.99.144.80: ICMP echo request, id 13146, seq 2, length 64
18:35:17.599898 IP 193.99.144.80 > 192.168.23.91: ICMP echo reply, id 13146, seq 2, length 64
```

## Question

What is preventing the ping packets arriving on NIC 2 to be relayed through NIC 1? What do I need to do to enable routing of these packets?

Comment: Is 192.168.1.111 able to use your Debian Router to communicate to the 192.168.23.0/24 network at all, or is it only connections that cross your other gateway(192.168.23.254) that aren't completed?
Also can the 192.168.2.0/24 network communicate with the 192.168.23.0/24 network and/or the 193.99.144.80?

Comment: I would keep rp_filter=1 whenever possible. Requiring an other value to work might mean there's an anomaly in the routing configuration. Anyway 0 is fine for troubleshooting. What would be the output of this command (that mimics your example but doesn't send any packet): `ip route get from 192.168.1.111 iif enx00e04c360e75 to 193.99.144.80`? The result can even change depending on `rp_filter`.  Also, still for troubleshooting, did you disable any firewall in place?

Comment: @ReedGhost: (1) Except for the Debian router box in question (192.168.23.91), 192.168.1.111 cannot communicate to network 192.168.23.0/24 at all. I tried to ping a collegues machine 191.168.23.98 but the connections didn't complete. I see the ping packets enter at one interface but they don't leave through the other. (2) Devices on the 192.168.2.0/24 network show the same behaviour as the ones in 192.168.1.0/24. That is, they can ping all the ip addresses of my Debian router box, but nothing else.

Comment: @A.B: (1) The output of your command `ip route get from 192.168.1.111 iif enx00e04c360e75 to 193.99.144.80` was `193.99.144.80 from 192.168.1.111 via 192.168.23.254 dev enp2s0 <newline> cache iif enx00e04c360e75`. (2) I'm not aware of any firewall running on my system. It's a Debian Stretch with KDE, but I made sure that the checkboxes `NetworkManager > <connection-name> > IPv4 tab > Routes > Use only for ressources of this connection` are unchecked.

Comment: Try this: disable docker (`systemctl disable --now docker; systemctl mask docker.socket`), reboot (yes really, docker makes a lot of network changes so unless you know which ones, reboot), and try again your routing attempt.

Comment: @A.B Unfortunately that didn't work. Docker is not running (neither do I have a docker0 interface) but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: ok I'm out of ideas (to revert: systemctl unmask docker.socket + systemctl enable --now docker)

Comment: @A.B You were right. I didn't notice that after rebooting with docker disabled, ipv4 routing (`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`) got disabled. After reenabling it, I could see the ping requests entering through NIC 2 (`192.168.1.1/24`) leaving through NIC 1 (`192.168.23.91/24`). NIC 1 never received any ping replies, but that's due to how the network infrastructure is configured, I assume. Pings to devices connected on NIC 3 (`192.168.2.2/24`) got replied to and showed up on the tcpdump output of both NIC 2 and NIC 3. If you provide your docker-related comment as answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing what was exchanged in comments:

- the system was not explicitly configured as a router

  Ie there is no explicit configuration that applies something like:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- the system is running Docker

  That means that:

  - Docker turns the system into a router

    It sets itself:

    ```
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    ```
  - Docker [prevents routing in the firewall policy](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router)

    > Docker on a router
    >
    > Docker also sets the policy for the FORWARD chain to DROP. If your
    > Docker host also acts as a router, this will result in that router not
    > forwarding any traffic anymore. If you want your system to continue
    > functioning as a router, you can add explicit ACCEPT rules to the
    > `DOCKER-USER` chain to allow it:
    >
    > ```
    > $ iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i src_if -o dst_if -j ACCEPT
    > ```

So

- having Docker dropped forwarded packets (except for containers)
- stopping Docker didn't enable forwarding anymore (at least on next boot)

In both cases the system didn't route in the end.

You should probably do both things below:

- enable routing explicitly (somewhere in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/`)
- follow Docker guide [in previous link](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router) to allow routed traffic

Comment: That is an incredibly structured and well written answer. Indeed, when rebooting the machine without docker engine running, everything behaved as expected. I just had to turn on kernel ip_forward manually.